# How to properly use image resource in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

What is the best way to store static images (like toolbox icons) in a WPF app?
Right now I have Images directory and use them like this:

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="rbSignOut" Content="Sign out" Glyph="Images/Icons/close-16x16.png" LargeGlyph="Images/Icons/close-32x32.png" />
```

I think it's not the best practice because when I move XAML file in to a subfolder, I need to change all paths. Also, it just does not seems right to store paths in code. So how do I do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of your path, which is relative to the XAML file:

```
Glyph="Images/Icons/close-16x16.png"
```

Use a path which is relevant to the application root (using a leading forward slash)

```
Glyph="/Images/Icons/close-16x16.png"
```

No matter where your XAML file is, your image will always be referenced from the root. As long as you don't move your images, you'll always be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ResourceDictionary together with your images. You can add it to the generic.xaml ResourceDictionary so you'll only have to change one path if you move it and you can use the images in every xaml file.

Answer (score 1):

Just Right-Click and change your image's "Build action" to "Content" and use like this

```
<Image Source="/WPFApplication1;component/Images/Image.png" />
```

I felt it as the best approach to use Images,Video etc as the Files are not embedded into the assembly.